Some questions related to meanders
Let $A_n$ denote the set of noncrossing fixed point free involutions
in the symmetric group $S_{2n}$. "Noncrossing" means that if
$a<b<c<d$, then not both $(a,c)$ and $(b,d)$ can be cycles of $w\in
A_n$. The cardinality of $A_n$ is the Catalan number $C_n
=\frac{1}{n+1}{2n\choose n}$. A meander of order $n$ may be
defined as a pair $(u,v)\in A_n\times A_n$ such that $uv$ has exactly two
cycles (necessarily of length $n$). Let $\kappa(w)$ denote the number
of cycles of the permutation $w$. The meander matrix
$\mathcal{G}_{2n}(q)$ is the matrix whose rows and columns are indexed
by elements of $A_n$, with $(\mathcal{G}_{2n}(q))_{u,v}$ equal to
$q^{\kappa(uv)/2}$.  Di Francesco has shown
here that
$$ \det \mathcal{G}_{2n}(q) =\prod_{m=1}^n U_m(q)^{a_{2n,2m}}, $$
where $U_m(q)$ is a Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind, and
$a_{2n,2m}$ is a certain nonnegative integer. (Note: Di
Francesco defines
$U_m(2\cos\theta)=\frac{\sin(m+1)\theta}{\sin\theta}$, while I think
it is more traditional to define
$U_m(\cos\theta)=\frac{\sin(m+1)\theta}{\sin\theta}$.)
What if we refine the definition of $\mathcal{G}_{2n}(q)$ by defining
$(\mathcal{H}_{2n})_{u,v}$ to be $\prod_i p_i^{\lambda_i}$, where $uv$
has $2\lambda_i$ cycles of length $i$? Here $p_i=\sum_j x_j^i$, the
$i$th power sum symmetric function. Then for instance,
$$ \det \mathcal{H}_6 = (p_1^3-p_3)^3 (p_1^6+3p_1^3 p_3 -6p_1^2p_2^2
  +2p_3^2). $$
We don't get as much factorization as for $\mathcal{G}_6(q)$, but
we do get some factorization. I was unable to compute
$\det\mathcal{H}_8$.
It is also true that the irreducible factors of $\det \mathcal{H}_6$
are Schur positive, i.e., nonnegative linear combinations of the Schur
functions $s_\lambda$. Does this property persist for all $n$?
The sum of the entries of $\mathcal{G}_{2n}(q)$ gives the enumeration
of pairs $(u,v)\in A_n\times A_n$ by half the number of cycles of
$uv$. For $n=3$ this is $5q^3+12q^2+8q$. What can be said about the
sum of the entries of $\mathcal{H}_{2n}$? I have checked that it is Schur
positive for $n\leq 6$.
My last question is only peripherally related to meanders. Let $R_n =
\sum_{w\in A_n} w\in \mathbb{Q}S_{2n}$, where $\mathbb{Q}S_{2n}$
denotes the group algebra of $S_{2n}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. What can be
said about $R_n$? For instance, its eigenvalues (when acting by left
multiplication on $\mathbb{Q}S_{2n}$), its mixing time (i.e., what is
the least $k$ (asymptotically) for which $(R_n/C_n)^k$ is approximately the uniform distribution on the set of even or of odd permutations in $S_{2n}$ (whichever is
appropriate)), etc? If all
eigenvalues of $R_n^2$ are real and nonnegative, then can we modify
the answer of Brendan Pawlowski at
MO254782 to
conclude that the sum of the entries of $\mathcal{H}_{2n}$ is Schur
positive?
Addendum. I computed $\det\mathcal{H}_8$. (It was almost
instantaneous on my home PC. I don't know why it failed on an MIT
Math. Dept. server.) It factors as $a\cdot b\cdot c^2 \cdot d^2$,
where $a,b,c,d$ are irreducible homogeneous symmetric functions of degrees $12, 12, 8, 8$, respectively. Each of $a,b,c,d$ is Schur positive.
Addendum2. Let $\mathrm{scp}_{2n} =
\det(\mathcal{H}_{2n}+I_{2n}x)$, essentially the characteristic
polynomial of $\mathcal{H}_{2n}$. I computed $\mathrm{scp}_6$ and
$\mathrm{scp}_8$. It seems remarkable to me that they factor in the
same way as the determinant (the case $x=0$). Moreover, for any $j$
the coefficient of $x^j$ in $\mathrm{scp}_6$ and $\mathrm{scp}_8$ is
Schur positive. For $\det(\mathcal{G}_6(q)+I_6x)$, the factorization
follows that of $\mathcal{H}_6$ (not $\mathcal{G}_6(q)$). For
$\det(\mathcal{G}_8(q)+I_8x)$, the factorization follows that of
$\mathcal{H}_8$ except that the two factors of degree 12 and
multiplicity two merge into a single factor of multiplicity four.

Not a full solution (only for Schur positivity): Consider the set of pairs $(u, v) \in A_n \times A_n$. We'll define a map that associates each such pair with a semistandard Young tableau $T$ of shape $\lambda(uv)$, where $\lambda(uv)$ is the partition corresponding to the cycle type of $w = uv$.
First, we represent each $u \in A_n$ as a noncrossing matching of $2n$ points labeled $1, 2, \dots, 2n$ arranged clockwise around a circle. The matching consists of $n$ chords inside the circle connecting the paired elements. Similarly, we represent each $v \in A_n$ with chords outside the circle, again connecting the pairs in $v$.
To determine the cycles of $w = uv$, we "follow" the paths created by the chords of $u$ and $v$. Starting at a point $i$, we move along the chord in $u$ to $u(i)$, then along the chord in $v$ to $v(u(i))$, repeating this process alternately using $u$ and $v$ until we return to $i$. This traversal defines a cycle in $w$. Since $u$ and $v$ are involutive, their matchings are perfect, and every point is included in exactly one cycle.
Now, we construct the tableau $T$ as follows: For each cycle $C$ in $w$, we collect the labels of the points encountered during the traversal and arrange them in increasing order to form a row of $T$. We then order the cycles (and hence the rows of $T$) according to the minimal elements of their respective cycles, in increasing order (see example below for $n=2$).
The resulting tableau $T$ has the following properties:

Its shape is $\lambda(uv)$, since the lengths of the cycles correspond to the row lengths in $T$.
It is semistandard: entries in each row are strictly increasing (as they are sorted lists of labels within a cycle), and entries in each column increase strictly down the tableau (ensured by the ordering of the cycles and the noncrossing property).

The weight of each tableau $T$ corresponds to a monomial $x^{\mathrm{wt}(T)}$, where the weight $\mathrm{wt}(T)$ records the multiplicities of the entries. In our case, since the entries are distinct and range from $1$ to $2n$, and the cycles determine the entries, the total monomial corresponds to the product $\prod_{i} p_i^{\lambda_i(uv)}$.
The set of all such tableaux $T$ of shape $\lambda$ is precisely the set of SSYTs of shape $\lambda$ with entries $1,2,\dots,2n$ and distinct entries. The generating function of these tableaux is the Schur function $s_\lambda$. Therefore, we have:
$$
S_n = \sum_{\lambda \vdash 2n} c_\lambda s_\lambda
$$
where $c_\lambda$ is the number of pairs $(u, v) \in A_n \times A_n$ such that $\lambda(uv) = \lambda$. Since $c_\lambda \geq 0$ (it counts the number of such pairs), $S_n$ is a nonnegative integer linear combination of Schur functions.
Example for $n = 2$
In $A_2$, we have noncrossing matchings on four points. Let $u$ pair $(1,2)$ and $(3,4)$, while $v$ pairs $(1,4)$ and $(2,3)$. Computing $w = uv$, we start at 1 and follow the path: $1 \xrightarrow{u} 2 \xrightarrow{v} 3 \xrightarrow{u} 4 \xrightarrow{v} 1$, forming a 4-cycle $(1,2,3,4)$. The resulting tableau $T$ has shape $(4)$ with entries $[1\ 2\ 3\ 4]$, which is indeed semistandard.
